# How do I build an un-ordered list dynamically from json data

Tags: php, javascript, html, json, html-lists

How do I modify this function that dynamically builds a drop down list so that I could build an un-ordered list dynamically from json data.

```
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        jQuery .getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/conn_mysql.php", function (jsonData) {
            $.each(jsonData, function (i, j) {
                document.index.spec_list.options[i] = new Option(j.options);
       });
     });});
</script>
```

*spec_list* is id of drop down i.e. 'select' here & *options* i.e. in (j.options) is the field in table which data is received as json. I have *'msg'* only table field now which data is to be used to dynamically populate 'ul id="msg"'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it sounds like you want to append `li` elements to an existing `ul` with the ID "msg", where the content of each `li` comes from the `.msg` property of each entry in the `jsonData`:

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/conn_mysql.php", function (jsonData) {
    var markup;

    markup = [];
    jQuery.each(jsonData, function (i, j) {
        // Note: Be sure you escape `msg` if you need to; if it's already
        // formatted as HTML, you're fine without as below
        markup.push("<li>");
        markup.push(j.msg);
        markup.push("</li>");
    });

    jQuery('#msg').append(markup.join(""));
});
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsbin.com/eveti5). (See the "off-topic" comment below; the working example uses one of the tricks mentioned.)

Or if the new `li`s should *replace* the existing ones in the `ul`, use

```
jQuery('#msg').html(markup.join(""));
```

...instead of `append`.

Either way, that uses the well-known "build it up in an array and then `join` it" idiom for building up markup, which is almost always more efficient (in JavaScript implementations) than doing string concatenation. (And building up the markup first, and then applying it with a single DOM manipulation call [in this case via jQuery] will *definitely* be more efficient than adding each `li` individually).

If you're not concerned about efficiency (this is showing the result of an Ajax call, after all, and if you know there are only a couple of `li`s to append...), you could do it like this:

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/conn_mysql.php", function (jsonData) {
    var ul;

    ul = jQuery('#msg');
    // If you want to clear it first: ul.empty();
    jQuery.each(jsonData, function (i, j) {
        // Note: Be sure you escape `msg` if you need to; if it's already
        // formatted as HTML, you're fine without as below
        ul.append("<li>" + j.msg + "</li>");
    });
});
```

...but if you're dealing with a lot of items, or if you were doing this in something that happened frequently, you're probably better off with the build-it-up version.

**Off-topic**: Your original code mixes using the `jQuery` symbol and the `$` symbol. Probably best to stick to one or the other, so I went with `jQuery` above. If you're not using `noConflict`, or if you're doing one of the nifty tricks for using `noConflict` but still being able to use `$`, you can safely change the above over to using `$` throughout.